# Создание файлов COMTRADE в C# при помощи GSF.Comtrade

Tags: c#

*Понимаю, что очень узконаправленный вопрос, однако оф. документация скупа на ответы*

---

Итак, имеется пара COMTRADE файлов (описание *.cfg и данные *.dat). Передо мной стоит задача взять все данные из этой пары и создать новую пару с теми же данными (для простоты примера).

Используя фреймворк GSF читаю файлы так:

```
    Parser comParser;
    private void openComtradeDatFile()
    {
        OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
        DialogResult dialogRes = od.ShowDialog();

        if (dialogRes == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            comParser = new Parser();
            if (File.Exists( od.FileName ))
            {
                comParser.FileName = od.FileName;
                ComtradeToChart();
            }

        }
    }
    private void ComtradeToChart()
    {
        // (Пере)Открыть файлы
        comParser.CloseFiles();
        comParser.OpenFiles();
        string cfgFileName = Path.ChangeExtension( comParser.FileName, "cfg" );
        comParser.Schema = new Schema( cfgFileName );
        // Номер канала
        int channelNumber = (int)numericUpDownChannel.Value;

        // Построение осциллограммы для текущего канала
        chartMain.Series[0].Points.Clear();
        while (comParser.ReadNext() == true)
        {
            chartMain.Series[0].Points.AddXY(
                comParser.Timestamp,
                comParser.PrimaryValues[channelNumber]
            );
        }
    }
```

Все работает и строится осциллограмма на чарте. Ок.

Пробую записать данные в новый файл (*.dat, ибо *.cfg в данном случае тот же):

```
private void экспортToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        // Открываем окно сохранения
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (saveFileDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {

            FileStream outFile = File.Create( saveFileDlg.FileName );
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outFile);
            // Читаем и Пишем:
            comParser.CloseFiles();
            Schema outSchema = comParser.Schema;
            comParser.OpenFiles();
            GSF.Ticks timestamp = 0;
            while (comParser.ReadNext()==true) {
                double[] vals = comParser.SecondaryValues;
                uint sample = 1;
                Writer.WriteNextRecordBinary( sw.BaseStream, outSchema, timestamp, vals,sample,false);
                timestamp = comParser.Timestamp;
            }
            outFile.Close();

        }
```

После всего получается, что в новом файле появилось много пустых записей каналов, и все остальное смещено на неопределенное число байт
[image: Получается следующее]

---

Как решить правильно данную задачу? Есть ли тут люди, работавшие с данным фреймворком(GSF.Comtrade)? Или возможно стоить обратить внимание на другие библиотеки/фреймворки?

Comment: Вы бы убрали никому не интересный код, который занимается показом диалогов, он-то к вопросу отношения не имеет?

Comment: А зачем вы создаёте `sw`? Вы им нигде не пользуетесь, а он, может, ещё и мешает.

Comment: Немного подчистил код, но убрать диалоги не решился, т.к. имена файлов хардкодить не хочется. А про StreamWriter, согласен, можно было создание BaseStream из файла сократить, но оставил для наглядности. Или я что-то делаю не так с этим sw?

Comment: Ну, как хотите. Как правило, чем длиннее ваш код, тем меньше шансов получить ответ, потому что читать лишние 10 строчек, только для того, чтобы понять, что это UI-обвязка, не имеющая никакого отношения к сути вопроса, не хочется никому.

Comment: Ну и вы всё же попробуйте убрать `sw`. Вы его не используете, а он при старте может перематывать поток, или что-нибудь ещё. Чем больше кода, тем сложнее отлаживать. Ваша цель ведь отладить, а не усложнить себе жизнь?

Comment: Спасибо всем за участие)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, справиться с данным фреймворком не вышло, так что в основу ответа легла библиотека Wisp.Comtrade. Теперь все выглядит достаточно просто и лаконично:

```
private void ExportComtradeWisp(string inFileName, string outFileName){
        int[] channelsToExport = new int[] { 0, 4, 7 };// например, хотим экспортировать Цифр. и Аналог. каналы 0,4,7
        Wisp.Comtrade.RecordReader comReader = new Wisp.Comtrade.RecordReader( inFileName );
        Wisp.Comtrade.RecordWriter comWriter = new Wisp.Comtrade.RecordWriter();

        // Добавляем нужные каналы в CFG
        foreach (var channel in channelsToExport)
        {
            comWriter.AddAnalogChannel( comReader.Configuration.AnalogChannelInformations[channel] );
            comWriter.AddDigitalChannel( comReader.Configuration.DigitalChannelInformations[channel] );
        }
        // Пишем каналы в DAT
        foreach (var time in comReader.GetTimeLine())
        {
            double[] analogs = comReader.GetAnalogsForTimestamp( time );
            bool[] digitals = comReader.GetDigitalsForTimestamp( time );
            List<double> analogsList = new List<double>();
            List<bool> digitalList = new List<bool>();
            foreach (var channel in channelsToExport)
            {
                analogsList.Add( analogs[channel] );
                digitalList.Add( digitals[channel] );
            }

            comWriter.AddSample( (int)time, analogsList.ToArray(), digitalList.ToArray() );
        }
        comWriter.SaveToFile( outFileName );

    }
```

Разве что пришлось написать расширение для выборки данных всех каналов для данной временной метки (timestamp):

```
//Пример расширения для аналоговых, вдруг кому понадобится
public static double[] GetAnalogsForTimestamp(this Wisp.Comtrade.RecordReader recReader, double time)
    {
        List<double> res = new List<double>();
        int count = recReader.Configuration.AnalogChannelInformations.Count;
        int index = Array.FindIndex( recReader.GetTimeLine().ToArray(), x => x == time );

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            res.Add(recReader.GetAnalogPrimaryChannel( i )[index]);
        }
        return res.ToArray();
    }
```